# Visual Studio Rebuilds projects when switching from debug to release and vice-versa when option XML documentation is selected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, rebuild

I've a very similar problem than described in the following question
[Visual Studio C# projects force a rebuild when switching from debug to release and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32956136/7556646).

I've C# two projects and one has project reference to the other. 
If I build (F6) in Debug and than I build (F6) in Release. If I now switch back to Debug and build (F6) it should be up to date.

That's is actually the case. So I can see that in the bin/Debug folder the file date and the assembly version are not changing.

But if I switch on the XML documentation file for the project which has project reference to the other under Project Properties / Build / Output for both configurations (Debug and Release) then the projects gets rebuild every time I switch from Debug to Release or vice-versa.

To recreate the issue:

1. Click `File` / `New Project...`
2. Create a new `Visual C#` --> `Console Application`.  Leave the generated code as-is.
3. Right-click on the new solution in the solution explorer and select `Add` -> `New Project...`
4. Choose `Visual C#` --> `Class Library`.  Leave the generated code as-is.
5. Right-click on the `ConsoleApplication1` in the solution explorer and select `Add Reference...`
6. Check the box next to `ClassLibrary1` in `Solution` -> `Projects` and hit `OK`.
7. Switch on the `XML documentation file` for the `ConsoleApplication1` under Project `Properties` / `Build` / `Output` for both configurations (`Debug` and `Release`)
8. Build the project in `Debug` configuration.  It builds, as expected.
9. Switch to `Release` configuration and build again.  It builds, as expected.
10. Switch back to `Debug` and build again.  It *builds*, and it shouldn't.  It's already been built, right?  All we did was change the target configuration selection.

I'm getting the following build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Build started 07.09.2018 13:46:43.
1>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>CoreCompile:
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /doc:bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.XML /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:H:\CSharp\TestRebuild\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:exe /utf8output Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\WO\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
1>_CopyAppConfigFile:
1>Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
1>  Copying file from "obj\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe".
1>  ConsoleApplication1 -> H:\CSharp\TestRebuild\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.41
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If `XML documentation file` is switched off I'm getting the following build output (it skips the CoreCompile as it should):

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Build started 07.09.2018 13:50:17.
1>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>CoreCompile:
1>Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>_CopyAppConfigFile:
1>Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
1>  ConsoleApplication1 -> H:\CSharp\TestRebuild\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.07
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Is this a bug?  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio Rebuilds projects when switching from debug to release and vice-versa when option XML documentation is selected

Yes, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2922) for Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015. It's just a faint shock that would not affect our build results except for the extra 0.00001 second execution time.

And this issue has been fixed in the Visual Studio 2017 version **15.6**. I have test it on the latest version in Visual Studio 2017 15.8.2 (Current), it works as expected.

You can find the `UseSymboliclinksIfPossible="$(CreateSymbolicLinksForCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryIfPossible)"` was added to the copy task in the target `CopyFilesToOutputDirectory` in the file `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`:

```
<Copy
    SourceFiles="@(IntermediateAssembly)"
    DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)"
    SkipUnchangedFiles="$(SkipCopyUnchangedFiles)"
    OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
    Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
    RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
    UseHardlinksIfPossible="$(CreateHardLinksForCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryIfPossible)"
    UseSymboliclinksIfPossible="$(CreateSymbolicLinksForCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryIfPossible)"
    Condition="'$(CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory)' == 'true' and '$(SkipCopyBuildProduct)' != 'true'"
        >

  <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="MainAssembly"/>
  <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>

</Copy>
```

If this bug affects your work, you can update your Visual Studio to the 2017.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tested it with Visual Studio 2017 15.7.6 and 15.8.2 and there are no unnecessary rebuild anymore.

Comment: With Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.7.5 I've those unnecessary rebuilds again.

Comment: Still not solved in Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.21.

Comment: A file `build.force` in the `obj` folder is created when switching configuration. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618943/7556646